# Tomcat fails after a reboot

Tags: tomcat

Yesterday our web servers worked fine.  We rebooted them last night.  Now our apps won't come up.  As near as I can tell, the reason is that Tomcat can't see the naming-resource jar.

```
[tennis@Server bin]$ /usr/bin/tomcat5 run
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat5
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat5/temp
Using JAVA_HOME:       /usr/java/jdk1.6.0
Mar 20, 2011 12:24:54 PM org.apache.commons.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw error
java.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/naming/resources/ProxyDirContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
```

When I look at /usr/share/tomcat5, I don't see anything out of the ordinary:

```
[tennis@Server bin]$ ls -las /usr/share/tomcat5/common/lib
total 556
   4 drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root         4096 Dec 20  2004 .
   4 drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root         4096 Dec 13  2004 ..
 348 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root       351403 Jul 21  2004 jasper-compiler.jar
 108 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root       105431 Jul 21  2004 jasper-runtime.jar
  28 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        27933 Jul 21  2004 naming-common.jar
  16 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        14820 Jul 21  2004 naming-factory.jar
   4 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root         2075 Jul 21  2004 naming-java.jar
  44 -rw-r--r--    1 root     root        42300 Jul 21  2004 naming-resources.jar
```

Now, I am not the sysadmin nor did I configure this.

I'm not really sure how to proceed now - would anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I grepped the naming-resources.jar file successfully for references to ProxyDirContext.

Comment: I hacked the naming-resources.jar file into the CLASSPATH in /usr/bin/dtomcat5 and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that our SAN was corrupted.  We had tons of missing JAR and PDF files, as well as some JAR files that were corrupted.  Why our (outsourced) data center support staff didn't monitor this and tell us the SAN was coming apart, I do not know.  I bet we find out.  Oh yes, we will find out.

I also learned our SAN is probably not even RAIDed. /rolleyes

The evil dark side of outsourcing.